# Deleting same, but different html code across all html documents

Tags: html, windows, duplicates, contains

I'm just wondering how to delete the same, yet different html code in an html page. Or to be able to do this for multiple pages at once too if that's possible.

What I mean by this is html code that has the same beginning, and same end, but not the same middle content between them compared to other .html pages.

The middle may seem similar, but is actually different across all html documents, such as a slight change in a link from page to page. 
Or, the middle's code can be entirely different compared to other documents, diverging.

Is there any tool out there where you can specify delete from `<span STYLE=` to `</span>` where the middle content is `"font-size: x-small; color: #90c040">example link` with the middle content varying between different html pages?

If you could specify the beginning and end code to be deleted, and delete everything that's inbetween it, and do this with a one push button that you can specify the parameters, that saves those parameters so you don't have to enter it every time, that would be great.

Or if it could allow you to do multiple html pages at once selecting them manually, a whole bunch at once , or possibly specify a folder and look for every html page in that folder, and delete the html code if it exists once you do it ( if it doesn't exist, then it moves to the next file. )

Thanks! I'm just wondering. Any help is much appreciated! ^_^~

**~Update! I've found a program that works!~**

I found a link with the programs, Notepad++, TextCrawler, Search & Replace Master, Ecobyte Replace Text, and InfoRapid Search & Replace. I also found multiple file search and replace.

− Notepad++ didn't allow wildcard * or start/end functions.

− TextCrawler as well as InfoRapid Search & Replace didn't work.

− Search & Replace Master was finicky. It didn't work at first, then it did after re-opening the program.

− Ecobyte Replace Text worked the best. This deleted everything beginning to end that I didn't want across many different .html files. I could specify what I wanted with the 'range function'.

− Multiple file search and replace worked too, but functioned differently. If you're looking to keep the beginning and end code, but not what's in the middle, then this one would work for you.

**Examples:**

Ecobyte will delete `<span STYLE=` to middle content inbetween to `</span>`
Leaving you with none of that code remaining.

Multiple File Search will ***not*** delete `<span STYLE=` & `</span>` but it **will** delete all of the middle content inbetween. 
This leaves you with `<span STYLE=` & `</span>` but no code remains if that was inbetween the beginning and end code you specified.

I hope this helps anyone else looking to delete code with the same beginning and end, but different middle code. Cheers! ^_^~

Picture if anyone needs: [html different text replacer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfHr.png)

Comment: Yeah, put it in a text editor and use the find and replace feature. Put in the sequence of characters you would like to replace or delete and let the thing to its magic. Notepad++ has this for instance.

Comment: Hi, notepad++ couldn't do what I wanted. I'm looking for a wildcard function that deletes all information say between `<style>` and `</style>` but the content between opening and closing `<style>` is different for all documents. Notepad++ won't do wildcard functions as far as I know, just a straight simple one line replace/delete.

I'll update my post with my findings, as I've found something that works.

Thanks for your help! It's much appreciated. =)